# jQuery - change a list of elements to an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, associative-array

Given an associative array (of the sort returned by `jQuery.serializeArray()`) like this:

```
[
{ 'name': 'abc', 'value': 'aaa', '__proto__': [Object] },
{ 'name': 'def', 'value': 'bbb', '__proto__': [Object] },
{ 'name': 'abc', 'value': 'ccc', '__proto__': [Object] }
]
```

How can one convert this, using either jQuery or just javascript, to an associative array of `name: [values]` like this:

```
{
   'abc': ['aaa', 'ccc'],
   'def': ['bbb']
}
```

This seems to essentially be the inverse of this question: [Build associative array based on values of another associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685516/build-associative-array-based-on-values-of-another-associative-array)... but in Javascript (not PHP). I wasn't able to find this question on Stackoverflow, though I thought it would have been asked.

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to iterate over the objects, check if the `name` exist on the result, and store or push the value, e.g.:

```
var result = {};
$.each(arr, function (index, el) {
  if (!result[el.name]) {
    result[el.name] = [el.value];
  } else {
    result[el.name].push(el.value);
  }
});
//{"abc":["aaa","ccc"], "def":["bbb"]}
```

Comment: Thank you; that'll do it. :) It crossed my mind, since it seemed such a common operation, that there may be something built into jQuery to do this (e.g. $.map/merge), or some set_default (like Python) to avoid the if/else.